# Another formula request

Tags: excel-formula

This time I would like help creating a formula that calculates a payment every 28 days (28 days, continuously, not 28 day of month).

Here's an example of how I intend to use the formula:

I have online newspaper access and I am billed to my credit card every 28 days.  I am next due for billing at 9 February 2017.

So I want to write a formula that will calculate the result of =(5*4), every 28 days, starting from 9 February 2017.  Otherwise, show $0.00 (eg 0*0).

As always, I appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Matthew

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Lukas V, thanks for your reply.  I've tried the following formula, to no avail. =IF(Income!$A$3=(sum(9/2/2017), 28), (5*4), 0).  Any assistance would be gratefully appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply dragging the formula down, you can use the following formula assuming your start date 9/2/2017 is in `A1`:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(A1),28)=ROW($A$1),5*4,0)
```